# Issue with Coded UI hand written Test cases

Tags: browser-automation, coded-ui-tests

I have a test case with below mentioned code:

```
[TestMethod]
public void _001_Search()
{
    BrowserWindow brw = BrowserWindow.FromProcess(proc_browserProcessNo);
    TopLeftNavigationLinks_Elements.ClickLink1TopNavigationLink(brw);
}
```

It uses two non-test methods:

Method1:

```
namespace Links
{
    public class TopLeftNavigationLinks_Elements
    {
        public static void ClickLink1TopNavigationLink(BrowserWindow brw)
        {
            //Find the Link1 top nvaigation menu link and click it
            var elementName_ToBeLocated = LocateUIElementByIdentifiers.GetElementLocators_FromUiElementsSheet(str_sheetName, "ele_Link1");
            GenericFunctions_ForLocatingElements.FindHyperLink_Click(brw, elementName_ToBeLocated.Item1.ToString());
            logger.Info("Link1 was found and clicked");
        }
    }
}
```

Method2:

```
namespace Functions
{
    public class GenericFunctions_ForLocatingElements
    {
        public static HtmlHyperlink FindHyperLink_Click(BrowserWindow brw, string str_uiElementPrimaryLocator)
        {
            XmlConfigurator.Configure();
            Boolean bol_hyperLinkFound;
            HtmlHyperlink html_hyperLink = new HtmlHyperlink(brw);
            //Verify if the browser window exists or not
            if (brw.Exists)
            {
                html_hyperLink.SearchProperties.Clear(); //Clear the existing Search Logic
                Console.WriteLine("1");
                //Find the HyperLink with the InnerText verify if it exists or not
                html_hyperLink.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlHyperlink.PropertyNames.InnerText, str_uiElementPrimaryLocator, PropertyExpressionOperator.Contains);
                Mouse.Click(html_hyperLink);
                Console.WriteLine(str_uiElementPrimaryLocator);
                bol_hyperLinkFound = html_hyperLink.Exists;
                Console.WriteLine(bol_hyperLinkFound.ToString());
                //Verify if the HyperLink exists or not with the specified Search logic
                if (bol_hyperLinkFound)
                {
                    logger.Info(html_hyperLink.ToString() + " found by InnerText");
                    if (html_hyperLink.Enabled) //Verify if the HyperLink is enabled or not
                    {
                        Mouse.Click(html_hyperLink); //Click the HyperLink
                        Console.WriteLine("3");
                        logger.Info(html_hyperLink.ToString() + " is clicked");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        logger.Info(html_hyperLink.ToString() + " can't be clicked because it is not enabled");
                        Assert.IsTrue(html_hyperLink.Enabled, "HyperLink with InnerText " + str_uiElementPrimaryLocator + " is not enabled");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //Display this message if HyperLink not found by InnerText
                    logger.Info("HyperLink with InnerText " + str_uiElementPrimaryLocator + " not found");
                    Assert.IsTrue(bol_hyperLinkFound, "Hyperlink with InnerText " + str_uiElementPrimaryLocator + " not found on the " + brw + " window.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Assert.IsTrue(brw.Exists, "Browser window for finding the Hyperlink with InnertText " + str_uiElementPrimaryLocator + " does not exist");
            }
            return html_hyperLink;
        }
    }
}
```

Now the issue is, Coded Ui is not Clicking the HyperLink, it is able to find the same but not clicking the link. While if I use the following code in Method1 and doesn't use Method2, Mouse Pointer is moved to that link and it is able to click the same.

```
namespace Links
{
    public class TopLeftNavigationLinks_Elements
    {
        public static void ClickLink1TopNavigationLink(BrowserWindow brw)
        {
            //Find the Link1 top nvaigation menu link and click it
            var elementName_ToBeLocated = LocateUIElementByIdentifiers.GetElementLocators_FromUiElementsSheet(str_sheetName, "ele_Link1");
            HtmlHyperlink h = new HtmlHyperlink(brw);
            Console.WriteLine(elementName_ToBeLocated.Item1);
            h.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlHyperlink.PropertyNames.InnerText, elementName_ToBeLocated.Item1, PropertyExpressionOperator.Contains);
            Mouse.Click(h);
            logger.Info("Link1 was found and clicked");
        }
    }
}
```

Why Coded UI is not able to Find and Click the element using Method1 and Method2 both.

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution for the above issue, the code line `html_hyperLink.SearchProperties.Clear();` was causing problem, after removing this line test cases are working fine as required.